# Why would including an empty file make a PHP script fail?

Tags: php

The following script fails if line #6 (.include ...) is uncommented - no matter what the content of the file "somefile.php" is. Even for a 0-byte (empty) file. I was trying to move such functions and create a "utils.php" library, is that a big no-no in the PHP world? Error_log is empty. I am using PHP 5.2.17 on Linux 2.6.32. Thank you.

```
<?php // File: index.php
error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);

//Uncomment the following line and the script fails
//.include "somefile.php";

function imageToBrowser ($pseudonym, $filePath) {
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0', false);
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
        header("Content-Length: ".(string)(filesize($filePath)));
        header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$pseudonym.'.png"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        if ($file = fopen($filePath, 'rb')) {
                while(!feof($file) and (connection_status()==0)) {
                        print(fread($file, filesize($filePath)));
                        flush();
                }
                fclose($file);
}}

if (isset($_GET['showImage']) && ($imageMask = $_GET['showImage'])) {
        imageToBrowser ($imageMask, 'Clear64.png'); // Use any .png file in $cwd
} else {
        echo "<html><body><center>\n";
        echo "<img border='0' src=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?showImage=365\" alt=\"Missing Image\"/>\n";
        echo "</center></body></html>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the exact error occurring? Saying it does not work does not give us an idea of why.

Comment: Hopefully you also remove the dot before `include` when you uncomment the line.

Comment: The page is empty (blank). No error message, and certainly not the image I get with that line commented out.

Comment: May be that is my problem (the dot). Checking ...

Comment: Don't set `display_errors` from inside your script. It won't have any effect if your script fails before it starts executing, for instance because of a syntax error. Set it inside your php.ini file or inside a `.htaccess` file if you're using Apache.

Comment: may be empty php file have some whitespaces..  not sure

Comment: Yes, that dot was creating the problem. Silly noob error. Thanks for the tip about ini_set().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no `.` before include. Dot is a concatenation operator in PHP and irrelevant here.

Also please note that your `ini_set ('display_errors', 1);` statement won't help with parse errors for obvious reasons. Better set your settings in `php.ini` or web-server config.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove dot before the include statement

The require() function is identical to include(), except that it handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the include() function generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop.

Similarly The require_once() statement is identical to require() except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

So please it will be better for you to used

```
require_once('somefile.php');
```

Comment: Please don't indent all the text in your answers. Doing so causes it to be printed out in unwrapped monospace text as if it were program code.

Comment: Using parenthesis like that makes `require_once` look like a function call, which it is not.